# How to get the image attachement custom link with PHP - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, attachment

This will return the link to the attachment:

```
    $link=wp_get_attachment_link($image->ID);
```

However, I can't find a way to get the LINK TO value from the ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS of an image. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: This is not data that is saved, but only data that is used when you insert an attachment to a post. It only affects the <img> tag being written to the post.

Answer (score 0):

As yoavmatchulsky wrote, this field is dynamically filed by ~wp-includes/js/media-views.js after you manually choose an image
but if you have an id of attachment, use  wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size);
as size use 'full'
full ref. in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link)

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are trying to use a custom link, the method described [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-custom-fields-for-attachments-in-wordpress--net-13076) might help.

Basically, in your functions.php, you could add a code similar to this:

```
// Adds a custom url field to your attachment
function attachment_custom_url( $form_fields, $post ) {
        $form_fields['video-url'] = array(
        'label' => 'CustomURL',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_url', true ),
        'helps' => 'Add custom URL, if applicable',
    );
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'attachment_custom_url', 10, 2 );

function attachment_custom_url_save( $post, $attachment ) {
if( isset( $attachment['custom-url'] ) )
update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'custom_url', esc_url( $attachment['custom-url'] ) );                        
    return $post;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'attachment_custom_url_save', 10, 2 );
```

And then, you could call it in your php like so:

```
<?php 
<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_url', true).'">Custom Link</a>;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I solve this by getting the post meta of the attachment, which was easier to me.

In my installation, custom URL input is shown like this:

```
<input type="text" class="text" id="attachments-140443-foogallery_custom_url" name="attachments[140443][foogallery_custom_url]" value="https://mycustomurl.com">
```

So, I assumed that if the first brackets contains the post ID, the second one is a meta key to save this value on wp_postmeta table. And there it was, just starting with the underscore character so it would be a hidden meta data. Therefore, the easier way to get this value is like this:

```
get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), '_foogallery_custom_url', true);
```

Of course you need to check if the post does have a thumbnail, but that's easy to adapt.